# How to create a CFuncType in Python

Tags: python, callback, ctypes

I need to pass a callback function that is CFuncType (ctypes.CFUNCTYPE or ctypes.PYFUNCTYPE...).

How can I cast a python function to CFuncType or how can I create a CFuncType function in python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I forgot how awesome ctypes is:

**Below is Copied from http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html**

So our callback function receives pointers to integers, and must return an integer. First we create the type for the callback function:

```
CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int))
```

For the first implementation of the callback function, we simply print the arguments we get, and return 0 (incremental development ;-):

```
 def py_cmp_func(a, b):
     print "py_cmp_func", a, b
     return 0
```

Create the C callable callback:

```
cmp_func = CMPFUNC(py_cmp_func)
```

Comment: Oh, yeah! That just did the trick. thanks.

I pass that cpm_func to a ctypes.Structure that has a field
'callback', ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(c_int, POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int))

Comment: What would you do if the return type of the callback is `void`? There is no `c_void` to specify as the first argument of `CFUNCTYPE`.

Comment: From [this](https://gitorious.org/telldus/telldus/commit/1108f3fad26f744c2418d22a547a17669522ce2e) it looks like `None` should be used.